# How can I invest or work with Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I have been a technologist for 30 years.  I was ecstatic about google when it first appeared - I was literally running around telling people about it.  Now I am doing the same about Stack Overflow.  I believe it is the way of the future, will replace monster.com pretty much completely, will be part of new social intelligence media for work and so much more.

I could go on for a long time but I can sum it up as "Resume? forget it, should me their reputation, the kind of questions they ask, the kind of answers they give, the comments they make".  Resumes and stupid interviews in many professions will soon take second place to your Stack Overflow score and reputation.

I'm kind of an evangelist for Stack Overflow and am always talking about it at out local ruby group meetings and it gets a lot of interest which is also very telling.  How can I get more involved behind the scenes?  I love writing unit tests!

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring

Comment: A great way to get noticed is to visit [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) and write something awesome, tests included :) Alluding to LISP in comments won't hurt.

Comment: @TinyTim Why LISP? Used in the backend?

Comment: @hus787 No, at least not that I know of, but strong opinions on functional programming would definitely help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring